# TLB Error on Windows 10

Tags: cpu

Recently I custom build a new computer. I've been running it for a week and starting yesterday, it would randomly restart. I looked at the event log I am getting the following errors:

```
Event 19

A corrected hardware error has occurred.

Reported by component: Processor Core
Error Source: Unknown Error Source
Error Type: Translation Lookaside Buffer Error
Processor APIC ID: 31
```

Another similar error that is popping up:

```
Event 18

A corrected hardware error has occurred.

Reported by component: Processor Core
Error Source: Machine Check Exception
Error Type: Translation Lookaside Buffer Error
Processor APIC ID: 31
```

I am currently using AMD Rysen 9 3950X Unlocked processor. It is ITX build with smaller than usual box. Fan cooled. I went to local computer store and asked for advice and they kept saying it needs a larger box and better cooling. On average, its running at 70 degrees. The personnel at the store tells me that temp is like frying the CPU.. Not sure they even really understand the problem. This is my first ever custom build.

```
Parts:
CPU: Ryzen 3950x
Mother Board: Asus ROG Strix X570-I
Power: Silverstone SX650-G 650W
Cooler: Noctua NH-C14S, Premium CPU Cooler with NF-A14 PWM 140mm Fan
Ram:Corsair Vengeance LPX 64GB
```

Comment: 70 degree Celsius or Fahrenheit? 70° Celsius would really be a lot. This is a strong indicator that you have not correctly mounted the heat-sink and the CPU is overheating.

Comment: @Robert they do idle quite hot. To the OP; are you using a stock HSF? Or an after market such as Noctua or BeQuiet! ?

Comment: so its in celsius. I am currently using Noctua NH-C14S, Premium CPU Cooler with NF-A14 PWM 140mm Fan

Comment: Did you apply the thermal paste correctly? Or does that HSF have a contact pad?

Comment: ya, the paste comes along with the fan and I am just applying it on top of the cpu between it and the fan cooler

Comment: What's your ambient room temperature? Does the CPU temperature go down [even just slightly] if you run the machine with the side off? If so you need better throughput. Intake fan[s] on the front, exhaust on the back &/or top. If not, then either your thermal contact isn't good enough [re-do it from scratch] or your cooler is not up to the task.

Comment: Please add the exact model of the motherboard, CPU and RAM. I also suggest running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many passes. This tests RAM, memory controller and CPU. If any errors are found, then post the results file.

Comment: Added all my parts. thanks. Will do memtest86 tonight and post back.

Comment: Its a processor memory management error, maybe you have a faulty processor.>>>>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer